# Using a button outside a form to submit form and trigger jQuery validation

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, validation

I'm using the jQuery validation plugin and the form uses ajax to submit the form.  I have a floating button bar which generates the buttons for pages depending on what the page is used for.  These buttons sit outside of the form tag.  My form's id is account-settings.  In my document.ready I have this:

```
$("#account-settings").validate({
        rules: {
              email: {email: true}
               },

         messages: {
                      email: {email: "Enter a valid email address."}
               },
    })
```

There's a button called savesettings which saves the settings for the form. Here's the click event:

```
$('#savesettings').click(function() {  

 if($('#account-settings').valid()){
    alert("Valid form");
}
else{
    alert("Not valid");
}
}
```

Nothing happens when I click the button... so, basically, I'm obviously not using the plugin right, somebody enlighten me?  Keep reading over the documentation but I don't see anything else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to serialize the form upon the user clicking the button something like..

```
$('#savesettings').click(function() {  

 var $as = $('#account-settings');

 if($as.valid()){

    $.post(
        /* your server page */
      , $as.serialize()
      , /* your callback function */
    );

  }

  else{
    alert("Not valid");
  }

});
```

I should point out the obvious accessibility pitfall with submitting a form this way where users with no JavaScript will not be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit a form using any button outside of that form, you should use the `trigger()` function like so:

```
$('body').on('click', '#my-button', function(){
    $('#account-settings').trigger('submit');
});
```

Your validation plugin should then act as normal.

Comment: I guess it would have been good to mention I'm using ajax to submit the form so this won't quite work for me.

Comment: Ah right, actually I assumed you had code within your submit() function to handle everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Your JS function could use a closing paren. Try something like:

```
$('#savesettings').click(function() {  
  if($('#account-settings').valid()){
    alert("Valid form");
  } else {
    alert("Not valid");
  }
});
```

Comment: You might try ditching the if/else part for now and just put an alert in there to make sure the button is firing the click event as expected. If it does, then your problem is most likely due to the validation stuff. If you still don't get an alert, then there is probably a problem elsewhere. Using the javascript console in Chrome, or using Firebug can really be helpful when tracking down javascript errors since most often the error will cause something to be printed out in the console indicating what the issue is.